# Javascript facebook login get email

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I am trying to allow users to register and login on my site using facebook, the following code works and I can see the users name and ID in the response.

However, I am unsure how to get the email address of the user. I have checked that my app is live on facebook developers dashboard and the permissions and features section includes email.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    if(response.status === 'connected'){
        FB.api('/me', function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
});
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
    FB.init({
        appId:'326746698293638',
        cookie:true,
        xfbml:true,
        version:'v7.0'
    });
};
(function(d,s,id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document,'script','facebook-jssdk'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {  } )
```

by

```
FB.api('/me?fields=id,email,name', function(response) {  } )
```

and make sure you are using scope email on the login function, like this

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

See [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v7.0) for more details